# SwiftUI: The actual touchable area is bigger than I specify

Tags: ios, swiftui, touch

I am implementing a simple resize cursors for my drawing app, using SwiftUI.

[image]

Even though I am making the each cursor small (14x14 pixels), the actual hit area is much bigger (like 40x40) for some reason. I am wondering why it is happening, and figure out how to eliminate it.

Here is the code:

```
var body: some View {
        let center = scaled(point:model.cursorCenter)
        return ZStack {
            let rect = scaledCursor()
            Path(CGPath(rect: rect, transform: nil))
            .stroke(lineWidth: 1.0)
            .foregroundColor(selectionColor)
            if !model.isDragging {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width:14, height:14)
                    .position(CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
                    .foregroundColor(selectionColor)
                    .gesture(resizeGesture(geometry: geometry, sx:nil, sy:nil))
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width:14, height:14)
                    .position(CGPoint(x: center.x, y: rect.maxY))
                    .foregroundColor(selectionColor)
                    .gesture(resizeGesture(geometry: geometry, sx:1, sy:nil))
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width:14, height:14)
                    .position(CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: center.y))
                    .foregroundColor(selectionColor)
                    .gesture(resizeGesture(geometry: geometry, sx:nil, sy:1))
                Circle()
                    .frame(width:14, height:14)
                    .position(CGPoint(x: center.x, y: rect.minY))
                    .foregroundColor(selectionColor)
                    .gesture(rotateGesture(geometry: geometry))
            }
        }
        .transformEffect(model.cursorTransform(center: center))
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
```

Comment: you could try adding ".contentShape(Rectangle())" to every Rectangle, and similar for the Circle.

Comment: I have already tried it, but it won't solve this problem.